# Is there a way to use *.properties file in PowerBuilder

Tags: properties, powerbuilder

Is there a way to read a properties file using any kind of resource bundle in PowerBuilder as we do in Java? I tried searching couple of places but I couldn't find any resolution for the same. It would be great if someone can share you thoughts on this

Comment: The properties file format is required, or you can use the .ini file format?

Answer (score 1):

Speaking in absence of what "using" a properties file means in Java, you can at least use the FileOpen(), FileRead() and FileClose() set of functions to read the data.

Good luck,

Terry